# Save Python search results in variable and working with its elements

Tags: python, loops

Since I am pretty new to Python this might be an easy question for you!

I'd like to execute a process for all directories with a specific name in a given folder 'folder_a' (which includes 'folder_1','folder_2',...).

First question: How do I get a list of all the directories and folder_a? What I tried was:

> for sub_folders in glob.glob("*OPER*.safe"): print sub_folders

However, this only creates a string of all directories, which is not really helpful in my case.

Second question: If I have got the list and like to access each folder one by one with a for-loop, how do I do it?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate over the contents of a directory, you can use python's excellent `os.walk` function:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files is os.walk(root_dir):
  for d in dirs:
    if search_term in d:
      do_something_to_directory(d)
```

`os.walk()` generates tuples, with `root` being the directory where you start your iteration, `dirs` is a list of the directories, and `files` is a list of the files.

**EDIT:**  If you want to get the files from inside a certain sub-directory, iterate over the *files* and filter for the desired directory name. Try this to see what I mean:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(starting_directory_path):
  for f in files:
    absolute_path = os.path.join(root, f)
    if 'Desired Folder Name' in absolute_path:
      print absolute_path
```

Since `os.walk()` is recursive, all the files in all sub-directories will be in the `files` list.  You'll only want to use the `dirs` list is you're looking specifically for a directory.  All files will be in files.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Will, but how do I search for a sub folder in the folder (root)?

What I did was this:
import os
i=0
for (working_dir, dirs,files) in os.walk(working_dir):
    print working_dir
        for d in dirs:
             if ('Desired_Foldername') in d:
                 break


Now here is the problem: os.walk does not stop at the folder level in which 'Desired_Foldername' lies. Is there something wrong with the code?

Regards

Comment: @user28724 Edited.  try iterating over `files` and `dirs` to see what you get.  If you need a file from anywhere, you can get it from `files`.  GLHF